# Не соблюдается формат списков в LibreOffice при форматировании в html

Tags: html, format, libre-office

При форматировании doc текста в html через LibreOffice получаю другие значки на выходе. Так же эта проблема есть для вложенных списков (такого типа 1.1, 1.2 На выходе будет обычный список из 1, 2).

Пример:

**Исходный текст**

[image: Текст перед форматировкой]

**То что получаем на выходе при конвертации в html**

[image: Текст после форматировки]

Есть ли какие-либо плагины для полной форматировки или готовые решения этого вопроса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вас же предупреждает LibreOffice, сохраняя документ в формат `html`, документ сохранится с упрощенным форматированием. Сохраняйте не в `html`, сохраняйте в `odt`. Его можно поместить на web-страничку например, вот таким вот незамысловатым способом:

```
<script src="https://webodf.org/about/features/webodf.js"></script>
<script>
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
  var odfelement = document.getElementById("odf"),
  odfcanvas = new odf.OdfCanvas(odfelement);
  odfcanvas.load("myfile.odt");
});
</script>
<div id="odf"></div>
```

Визуализировать `odt` можно благодаря библиотеке [WebODF](https://webodf.org/). Есть разные варианты отображения: от простого, как в сниппете, до полноценного [viewera](https://webodf.org/about/features/documentviewing-demo.html) и даже [редактора](https://webodf.org/about/features/directformatting-demo.html).

Попробуйте [WebODF](https://webodf.org/). Если он сохраняет не всё форматирование, то большую его часть точно.

```html
<script src="https://webodf.org/about/features/webodf.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
  // Найти элемент, куда будем вставлять визуализацию
  var odfelement = document.querySelector("#odf"),
  // Создать OdfCanvas
  odfcanvas = new odf.OdfCanvas(odfelement);
  // И открыть файл используя URI
  // Здесь используется DataURI, поддерживаются все возможные виды URI
  odfcanvas.load("data:application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text;base64,UEsDBBQAAAgAAHR/gVFexjIMJwAAACcAAAAIAAAAbWltZXR5cGVhcHBsaWNhdGlvbi92bmQub2FzaXMub3BlbmRvY3VtZW50LnRleHRQSwMEFAAICAgAdH+BUQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAABtZXRhLnhtbI2TzXKbMBSF930KD+0WJCECSIPJrtNFM+lMnJnsPEKSsVosMUIO6dtX/MaJvegO3fsdzj1XUNy/nZrNq7SdMnoboAgGG6m5EUrX2+B59z3Mg/vyS2EOB8UlFYafT1K78CQd23ip7mhthWi2wdG5lgLQ933U48jYGsQQYlADwRwLX5XsvwazYhBvg7PV1LBOdVSzk+yo49S0Ui8W9J2l41jT2Rizeg34NNjil4DpvNCCr3B7ts2ICQ5kIweLDqAIgYV9a5T+cysHIoSAsbsOMZr8b4R5d2OI+fli4Tgol+0OWctiTMytZM4Tod+eLGOI4hChEKY7lFOUUJgV4AZXCE5nQQxDr4FoENwRmsAIoizNICG4AAs2eUmhnL/uUJzt+K7y1w7/QPnDXfo0u1wRH4X8L29kV5JP9Fye2Fpq6cXGlj9VZeXjmBhkEYziKP72wPjj08v+JU/3abK5IPatNb8ldyDHCWFcYo5RGsMMs0oQKHJ0EDAV/FClFU4rQpJ5hne7yX79cDvnE3RO8c1Yd6xqZMjNWbtt4O9nLKoTq6+Kphrm+FxtL0i01iyrLWuPayObO72xYinGJJ6r/OgF3Em78mlK5p72V9sflZNd69OH1ygmSQDKAnz4hMCt37X8B1BLBwj1dQjh4AEAAOwDAABQSwMEFAAICAgAdH+BUQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwAAABzZXR0aW5ncy54bWy1W1tz2joQfj+/IsN7CuTSJkySDpfQ0pLAAGnm9E3YC6iRJY8kB/j3ZyUMzQHcEpt9SgL2rrS379uVcvN5EYmTV9CGK3lbqn6olE5ABirkcnpbehq1T69Kn+/+uVGTCQ+gFqogiUDaUwPW4iPmBF+XphYoOeH4QqJlTTHDTU2yCEzNBjUVg1y/Vnv7dM0rW32yEFy+3JZm1sa1cnk+n3+Yn39QelquXl9fl/2360eVUpsHnezVyvzDZ5XKRXn19+Zp/9ehC0t36ReW/v7GNOelu7Ud1tu/u0n3svpxyi1EzjYn6cdO2W0Jl1x75TDfWK20773/v/MDn69rYCMVl9bf2GWM3wglp6W7arXy6eKmvCvmcNFdmNi9sivF5D7z0M72Cj67vKicFRP+Ffh0tn/Z1YvKp5zShzM1H0CIcQbNGZNTMFsaxkoJYLJ0Z3UC+XR0ZEOruYEHFUKW9AkT5mDxpxGLT7kMYQHhrrH2B5l/BwNeLw8zeSfcWqqxmjtju3gu4MrM2Lu6uLzKLzYzW66uK5d5xRo+FnD8ZPFiSdLbSx5k5onLwmKrbihrVZQhvHqRc+E/lYpGKGo74mZK20JFqcuWKrFNJZJIbid2Kr1aVHpDqZejZfauXdossErvX/vVdc6CZIYgILAQtjV+QLDyugxwiRCOYGF7iKQToTDzpyxYvr+87vnwbTHL+jqtj/sfQDw+HMFXHySaWeQD74HyPlZM2xAseGkraTORpYCdvYYBOK4C2wX7GPJ7iXXQ2EUN4l8OIjSPSTQGjwREu+mzKTTQZFOtEpm5p/xo7JXUpVTW+3NP6harO17+F83iGQ8IyMQ9mj8MIWwxy8bMwONuAqdIXT5krcpiHWgrvV3Tj+ZOB5/OpQSmWIWLVibGPVCt/ytHa0tXx8jS1+E1pYnabFEoSkZsbAYgMF1ekbZ0sK7KTGPkX2rKwtOQxMz8DjtggfH+8aLBJdPLw8Ibd+9c18caDDMlQthG0mN48YHZWQOX5pZfF3wqIxIDpZZxfCNi+oUCTjpTiajt/F2XIQKXfDFYG7quOWIiSISvmAR6mwiPXCYqMfcyxMqcnQoFlLQdftUTq57ikNlM1lOkNMd22Rp7PVg2wPSZZhTkKo7F0smeOpR5wFhwBZzZkSIHZ79FolpVD0O3KRdtw5gFuIuRwlAU0AQhKAIChTtuigaccoqo9lBdN5zJYaB5bP9IAgsygi6mJq2aFjfOGb3JxPm/rwx3xYAm1vyWelIsn5DWknJnV3m0yg6v/PYaMkTLGSakZFwQeZ3KNA/mWemwqaL4gUuXkKvhW2PZFpkNXAF1w0R7su+g+hlr2jBiItNkBfT8bitcoXG539Js7ps5AkwTPI4h7PPAJpoG0IRi1rqkfFSRL2IUWp7kWAN78WrW8EKhxwf0cGnwC6qwTgu+G0YQUW2PV1Q8/m/Bml88VkGDhEWvE7Ane+NfWOKpqu4QtyHgmxpTaPDVo8li0wcdIBNHtPr4kYS0CoFawHMix1H+RPfy++YrMPRMyoga4AZpzFgiajnAMBgotd29oMvcKUv16rKSc0bv3Y7bAJtsz73f29U1ES3QresBCKJUxHYGRYd3t75jw7wdWhWvWQ1BhiEa1E1zhm4L0A7r+eizxkc1oqofxFJkQ0s9KovZ4EDIFRBMbNOTjsJRpB5yni9CjZlopeerSB5IOtX9QbDnEMGHbs5RXlexcIDppyQJ7fGuGYABn811a7XrthFkHf5ReMcuEZweVQsmLBEUGpy3V9119lg154GLN9a3xFg+WTpGap65xd5XJkw0HD8hgSoVv+lGhzPtgrnNtXFhTZE/WIbqfmK6GrJhNGzafNNBIm5ohpCrIbAf75MQyAVuJICfoNX9ArfHQpqucasmuJ9Dlegg/+QT2083WvlNjGLSg48YoUCraC9IHsMR6928CWqK8ZRAjuJ3hASvyWQABO3vMBlbB6UInWYNpnX/F9lg6h1DqUK6MEdASyb+kigFJu1I8vYSvE/nV2dn58VvoWCUjf2xyYbvFL+T0mVymuyylvWtlDA3iU+c/gyprfuctwOY5mwHww+vOw2YruYuuSXcy/CP7xc9VD8gjn+AtjxgwlPb3mSCPIekqUf0TxvK1UUPTwfqxp8jEzED3B3xrjqmy8awodGkM76RZly45tIf+FDBG2hygFsdX20I2opEdST5qQjoQuerHfMdC74/KOgnMrAJ1TFbulhnF3cF1rVn/gpTRvWb8ensVIPBrHILyk1pBQzU/DsACafx3YYLqhFEsSA61xuDTxQBC9IjFiRoPRGmXnoAdEP2DZIiaSJfsTQ3MPs3cyUyTpvezhiMulQHoWg07ag+Ge/zEZzaqW6HlmmCw303OfmxunHek02hDEV7uaFjLpgxsZ22o9+7XAUxZc3d9DG98S+MLdqjSGczS3lrYE+UHeeOpL/jWN75v4Vy1n903P0HUEsHCNASbagzBwAAEzIAAFBLAwQUAAAIAAB0f4FRAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGgAAAENvbmZpZ3VyYXRpb25zMi9wb3B1cG1lbnUvUEsDBBQAAAgAAHR/gVEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAfAAAAQ29uZmlndXJhdGlvbnMyL2ltYWdlcy9CaXRtYXBzL1BLAwQUAAAIAAB0f4FRAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGgAAAENvbmZpZ3VyYXRpb25zMi9zdGF0dXNiYXIvUEsDBBQAAAgAAHR/gVEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYAAAAQ29uZmlndXJhdGlvbnMyL2Zsb2F0ZXIvUEsDBBQAAAgAAHR/gVEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYAAAAQ29uZmlndXJhdGlvbnMyL21lbnViYXIvUEsDBBQAAAgAAHR/gVEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYAAAAQ29uZmlndXJhdGlvbnMyL3Rvb2xiYXIvUEsDBBQAAAgAAHR/gVEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAcAAAAQ29uZmlndXJhdGlvbnMyL3Byb2dyZXNzYmFyL1BLAwQUAAAIAAB0f4FRAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJwAAAENvbmZpZ3VyYXRpb25zMi9hY2NlbGVyYXRvci9jdXJyZW50LnhtbFBLAwQUAAAIAAB0f4FRAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGgAAAENvbmZpZ3VyYXRpb25zMi90b29scGFuZWwvUEsDBBQACAgIAHR/gVEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMAAAAbWFuaWZlc3QucmRmzZPNboMwEITvPIVlzthALwUFcijKuWqfwDWGWAUv8poS3r6Ok1ZRpKrqn9TjrkYz3460m+1hHMiLsqjBVDRjKSXKSGi16Ss6uy65pds62ti2Kx+aHfFqg6WfKrp3bio5X5aFLTcMbM+zoih4mvM8T7wiwdU4cUgMxrSOCAkejUJp9eR8GjnO4glmV1F066CQefcgPYvdOqmgsgphtlK9h7YgkYFAjQlMyoR0gxy6TkvFM5bzUTnBoe3ix2C904OiPGDwK47P2N6IDKblXuC9sO5cg998lWh67mN6ddPF8d8jlGCcMu5P6rs7ef/n/i7P/xnir7R2RGxAzqNn+pDntPIfVUevUEsHCLT3aNIFAQAAgwMAAFBLAwQUAAgICAB0f4FRAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACgAAAHN0eWxlcy54bWztW+tv47gR/96/wvCh/aZYkuNN4l720N5zgd094Hb7+UBLtM0uJQokFdv713f4kiiZspU46eHSJkAQc4bD4W8eHD787Xf7gk4eMBeElffT5CqeTnCZsZyUm/vpvz7/FN1Ov3v7l2/Zek0yvMxZVhe4lJGQB4rFBDqXYpkJMZf3062U1XI22+12V7v5FeOb2effZooWSbyXs6nl3vA8pyHuNI7ns80sRxJFDwTvvnE99ltZBHskd3d3M011rDkrBkQnM+CI8ANoLxy3yDipQPOal0uGBBHLEhVYLGW2ZBUu3WyXPvdSY2Ra1owXY3srXr9vgeR2YE63sw9A1H8+vHf8ZV2sMB87mgJR26ijLsE0txKgi7WpEYP3FeZESUB0yRiLChGRUmLOqqXXuzMDLNFYfRSv35cycAnbmW8av1qzugTVwReDahmFPQm+SEMF1RtU20k6J7ibmc+uj0QrisfOQTP7I2ZbxEd7j2b2e2tx59TVTI1zc7Qb7QDACzHsD8greWKsxYzjinHZDjbPxw82z7umGNuTraFf2kDSOsV5a/TMr719dCj3QyPPGmiqmlMNSp7NMMWql5glV0mTwDJEsyd4r+q27EjoQMZYdsI61zPVx3eEk56TxDPF0yRQSsovwwlUUT09TqrRjR/g3p1k33ECOaTNl2MNtBc0WrMoY0UFgPbiTjxsRhv6YTMgxGg63k916tH97f/eojmfvnUr5JrB6rhGGY5ynFHx9lvjak3zxHxWY91Pf4WBPh2KFYP1CzR1XAWhhx6xFaLyiMDgfftIGOps7CDJ6VHOyPkkER9U1iOeEfMPThBNAyI0oTNVQ4k2uIQogugQOyLEOfnv64zkaPIzR2WOQzP+G6qY+HuHzTRdPvZniHUx+Yh3k99YgcrBwXt8I4bnVl7LURGZQQHxgAA2tUaMgT0Ex1jYLxi7g/UzW+QCtXpWGPaVx5vrYt2cVZ5grYOQuLhk7B84I/nkEyrF5CdE6QplXwahCfCOgWeUjrOhlGrbzR7EzSXHa1RTuzNxkq2uG46qLcmmjtd+jiqobjGXBKyr5ickZ18wrBeUQaH9zW2sfqcTtZJC9UtpQ1nrn+lkzZY7EBWxSuqVoGSR+my7iC3K2S4CbSFfR/v7aXw1z4og8dAjQjaVESzLOBIVyqCOi7aMk69MFRKKNb09yfygJpUds8KyNlbqEWtApgWZwjx2RG4jU76tERWej1WII413B21NUvwRqiVTY4DjkRwzw4potUVuAK3GimMEJQyYiGTSUVR1oXQrWA7dKY/kquNUBDKJWsvVjtWfjFPS6QhVNvgNq4TyumG1G3al99FsaoEBhlJZ1SzUxlkkryHnmd0KU8NLZey/dvQcWD3AvTRZkK9ATtJK6jaKyk2NNtCksik0ZFB3Sg5if/ixwQxLqLuiL5iXer5Gi96QEZQ9qBwK+JZXje94k/hqUTUGcKo46teto1idHOH7j8ejq7qM4n0oqekRG7qZeW/Ehrol/TEb0ruP09ainQQxJms0LjA96ctggO2h2uJSV/4RRXkOyGtddEagpCCN+iNdvqrLTNZGoMooMEuYN1jyfEw4X45yApmhVIPADmuRtAHbjZoKwGyj9f+u/edxbd/zsEtpfXfkuECk1LsG55PpEVNVi22fxZjV5wJfzlAlvAz/1Mgypxpe9qXYdzpz0LJiXAWS8lJYdMDlKAyuQuDSgSPOdr3BoaUX0l8wriLJNlhu1ambCtlzA/sDNlumMkc8nw5mFmdeigQAq6KvjcVjeb9glHtJYFAcNDSHtFFYlVIFus/wGRp+T+PfVyw/hNQ6lwMLxCFBAWSVqhCuU10htO0rJqU6m4XiIUnbXJRBSID0GtH+2twYQZcWpS4tEN2hgziXrby843Y9Lt0856ann8Ou20h+dBqyo1vup5fWTsJQge3o7SSGcmFwNifSmtXjPIfTtOEc1LXhGNa2zaNK3zY+z8RlyNdhuawoOnjRMPHJl8Tak8PowhAajcd7KBWeMtETOYMqkSPitON06XmnS5/L69x5zjiEvkd6i/eM3gCQcPTIrGrtfklW1cfm5i5Jb4lEl6LrSnfVFA9n2oH6zbSpHlDawq4S9tyjjW0ws9RA5xd3hnFVmqdrQ7fajvamd7Al3T+jLxEt76QvPZPd/3yR+5HxwpN8BPb5cktluCS8TFiOSfIUY/aqOVdTslpqa1D8oArf5NQqcjos005Y7jDZbKGIWjGaD0Zl2jek6eXI4b6NaYZ6Nwy6/2jTefgvTuO/eAb8R1XEA0ZaPN1IptJ6lJGOirNHGWmo9+VGSk8bKf2DjZQ+l5F6C9xltju37F1m2/BC9SLWn5+2/vwPtv78fzdEfyyqrbrh7ltgHATD1dwZz72wSPpnTSnW1jUXyyLsX4Zt0uMZNcVevdK7Ku+fGQzcx/vb/O5V+1Epc8R1omQ6IyrA94iSSNd5NmxPgttwnsT3RAn1Tj0hK40ZzTOT0DCOa+KzjPVSdykXw4+6ruudRyexOpHunC1/3e+7h8slK5vDBT1CDQU1NzdGxv0FoyQfYNmRXD3l00eEYQ6rYnt2PnjIvG+2Bb1TZl/F44PiQL+GpnuO9o2fzdXokaFHXKHqjQQqsy3jkTxUuJviHzbLvT3SUP8f3P9amrnjyA+gQ5tE7G5F0SqcR40wcXytom9h1a6X1bzZ2BiSu7eMKqayPquOCFwtD0erUXs1anpmuNQvmY6ove5HSGtY3GJ0DPivhjLtMepVy7KbHVpvOwDoROpNKYKlqLGKOnWxXfuG8UlMEH2iD5tJfUCA3Q0qWgEZ0vSmVG+fQmJ7LFa2blwzStkOLLU6mPMfiVZTb/DmZsqNr84tbt64Iw0dM0Rf1t5PI59iDzsoXsu2S4tzcNJAHcJzJNLpq0I6uYqTN0GkfUoHaUd4caTnrwzp9GYA6IbQw1m3vzjM168M5kV6PYBzS+kBbQgvjvTilSF9c3M7gHRL6SFtCC+O9JtXhXR6Fc/Dy6FP6SDtCC+O9M0rQzq9DS+HPqWHtCG8ONK3rwzpRThNe4Qezov/SpK+e2Uw39wN4dxSekAbwosjncSvCur5VXwdXg99SgdqR7gE6i7Jx79kEgu1/V2TTc31Y61JQ4jseeeaMak+h0yR2Bmbp8QPiNZY3QKaRtdReBDoR4N+n9IdFEVKnvvyjJrveA1xmQ8pSMIKOvEKkVaD0DCDF5/mAbZ+snR31x5IhNCxQloUlG0tjZQZ118VU8Wf93ZdS2ufrKszIpBJssgRzHAKT/DSA1i3czjwoSqSaYCpdwSmKfYYKoVtW5xYJ9SErT2wTu+ubgZnaIcAAGXEOFFfWbOmZlxyRKTv1Po5wsBThHCV0m3kVqGhN6mdl9x2xhtO8uYBfhar3xCHNXEaJK6QaOGIr27iN60GPh+vVwePb76Yh/mMtt2juZ4UyDHqK3KdIymfSSN+gm4PSnscLiajAu1bRUHJ9psdlkHgykFs/COGXf1tOx33ShgUBW/Q/IoniZMAD1qrl7chlsGzUpT/uxbSRIaJF9POIbE5j100T4b9s9w49tJl2PfdbLcYqaei+sPMh8BrPBbURulxWFpCgUQjoxnNNipJnWDtP87wdfbC2csOPfGz8Lfs3/4HUEsHCPY2syKiCgAApT8AAFBLAwQUAAgICAB0f4FRAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACwAAAGNvbnRlbnQueG1s5VxLcyO3Eb7nVyBMOVWp0pAcPvRgdulae732utaPsuQkNxU4A3IQzQwmAIYU9+T/kFMuOeSn+ZekG8A8SA6pobTS2quLJA66G43++gUIwxef3yYxWTKpuEhfdvxuv0NYGoiQp4uXnZ+v3njnnc+nf3gh5nMesEkogjxhqfYCkWr4TYA7VZNAqaF+2Ym0zia93mq16q6GXSEXvaufejjmaXarex1HvZBhGDdRD/r9YW/RC6mm3pKz1Z8KjttIJ40c/sXFRc+MlqSK7xHt9/7x3bvLIGIJ9XiqNE0DVnGFd3OVxHMhE7WHftCzwwVxKJK9koHCY0swY0mtAskzsGQu04mgiqtJShOmJjqYiIylhfkndeqJAc0+wanbciNtnTehOtpj4/PedzBofnz3rqBP82TGZNvZEFSl1zHbUJezOHQSgMU5mRXDbjMmOUqg8UQI4SUKYNNMimxS495YAdO0rT5IW+eNBbioY5aL0tHnIk9BdQiORrWswjUJdZF2FFQvrVotsnCCi579XPBoOotZ2zUY4vqMQURla+8xxHVuI+4udQ1R6dySrlo7ANBCUqlPKDN9YK5xT7JMSF1NNgzbTzYMN6FoyynmwDcoTVI5xd1obMFvvL11KG+HRhiUpslyGRujhEGPxQy5VM/v+mVCDWgc3MN7kW2yIWHDZEIEB9AZ9ZCn7ggHPcfv95CmTKExT2/2J3QcrelxUI3N+AHq1UHyleSQQ6p82RagWxV7cwF1L8nAoFtxh6n0tl0ew5wvwvl2KtvKxWq5aO05y8Uerawa7R3fKG343d+1tmDYmRY9gK06qlc+mEMv4M1pwLyQBbGavrDOXD4m9jNO/rLzA8x8uU5mAio2qF5QJTxebw1WQjBTKQb+fespO9prO4l/eJY75FxqKvcqWxu8Q8wryWk8aBBhBjaWake8BUvBaSD+1IordZf8d3nAQ0q+ljQNWdOK/0wzof66QWYfPXzuK3BtRb5nK/KTSGi6d/ItuhbTSyevosi4DqBFWVIwG1ahNmZvMkdbsz9g7g1bf2BEHqDWFgr7feV4uB6sW4HKPdBaK82Sh8z9WgoekkuaKvKGxvGMBjd7TdNA28Y8rXTs7Uup7jnNNcCheeAZOWWuNT83VvSjX87ltM+opAtJs6gYgAe4lTMfvDLhQcMgw04huGTyMqhWTGoObjEXptnxaMwXUB0ClpqSajn+mSvN52tPQbMHcldCQtc2p7GyC6zpe0D5wQdR3ii5qXdM00VOF0DNILfAgwBaJC1hhp8vj9BveB/9rkCd60H/eibC9Z0GnklGb7wZg84AWAMR50laefHjrWx0n5W940oXwzH8vTk4qPRumHD8GBPus1O5JZtAZwN+Cbtwej5m805tpEJki6a9EU8//Jr8Oz0moXLBUy9mc+iU+t3Ts9Mg6dQGJF9EOOKeGtNwqDtp8dCKxxTjbQyWwfvYvne232zHLf7gwt1TLbKdZzOhNZ7XFI9hH8K8iFl+v9//rLOd+xQ0gfqgPS01GFVlFLtxHjJhV0DjLKKlQ+RpoHOzV/NWMAybGDAq5NDKJUAXkxVwVqgppbPglgYIvUSEID+Wnp5VAUBn4EciUxUKTSY8gG20ziKWUs2OzuJXOyUIxe+NTfs0V1AzwIxi5dneX8RCAqfMoY2yRywCDMk1iEM8arJErtFIhZ71IWM8HUmRLyLPbcxTkR4g0uusiQbqPNdmT9T/jFiPqFX05nYcjGhGFX/P0I0y6zAx01A2PXQLc9iawh4QG52NeMLmsR5Pr7+qySvWUfIZFVVEQ9wE7+iegzrSLHLDAoW4lfPzQl4jp/UxPP3laS5ytQnAsg3Vhpn3UTrj3DCZGuNY/LdM7cGmlqb7ureKFg1f0Pr97jir8qwzdDH6vkzQzuLFwJffb0o0qdmNbRqsZssDBEZ93LbH7LapxTUql+P+oEHlcjTi20qXQ2+b1C5H9yu+h8TgxxJIW9aXd1xMBTRmRaqsiZUs5mzewFC6zL6gLAlcIqiSwm4iMidwVenc3JBhAa0IYrZksbPHLI/B3YgdxOewgI79WC/BXxgybODsrl85GstuDiledn797//KBFebqJbmDE+CtYrOYGTFQzx273fPTgdQNHBNh7TctwZ7GL+xhrKHhjFP5dDfAJ7d+kM8daJY2dqoXB9ySdCDBGfyVxHxdkmmNOLJUpPYLRIn2zycizgWKxZ6M0h0yALFq1ObvKhltSTsdy/646aGxoMGaDjerO62OShYKu9pXPReHKylj8Bh+AxwGHTHo+NgcBxPhsLoGaAw7PpnR0ZDwfJkOIyfBQ7n/rEwGI4nQ+H0GaAw6o5GR0ZDwfJkOJw9AxzG3f75cTA4jidD4fxZoHDmHxkNBcuT4XDxDHA47Q6PhMFxPBkKfv9ZwHBxfjQOluWhQNSG2+xbB3v3rU3Y1VHKJDPQkWeAp98dnB27DzQcTxZWg4dCY6WFXGUxXdvZFIr9/UL2O9u7HwTtL02g0d8tOL+xDX3DEd2o8fjtl1bHb79Jkz/m7r12oLrzH5fafy42rzTd6yCyAanxp4fUY+3vPypOp58aTo95AvBRkTr71JB6vDOCj4rT+aeH0+OdInxUpC4+NaQe75zho+KEhxOfGlCPdxLxGFDtHl/09l5OdQN44bH8gOwOcMX+lbO0uuS6+3Bzz+su+HjOFwpXsIt4G8e50tLcoMJlPEjYVXEh92FS4M8HC3lt35t6sJw3fJFLVgHcaPxs99rDj345ddPo4NAoGqC68fp3Nvvh9RvCFaEpYbeBubVGUrYCxiBKRSwWa6Ijqsla5CQAojnEAuEpESlxi8/g6c40X9kbKaozTcSMx4xkkUiZKhYKPFOYMmwpw7zhpje4TwiD3WkYMqNNOzErfsN//eU/6gRYwC1TSGRKxDm65301W7FZQnm8ww1wp6jYTIqVYlJ1HUXmkIl2hX7DKL7ii+AUJ0tb3uMDYIgFwKVEBRedAR3h+nM3R9QW/bfaQBoKQJMRxfGCEVmDVWhC3+Nd8TXJFZvn4NMRTuQRFYmVu5dLipeVFFlxHaEKNF0ToSMmQb25XlEJRAxfawKnXqPHgBPBmLl2b6xUMAIPOB1AORfSSAGTLfHcR5Dymn2aCm0yCam9y/Wyc339Bt85hWR8c3098C+u/eFgfO6fjobD4nKiZIDykpV33qcvwmASSEa1kNNXIddrSr4Au+oXvdoAEoVUs+mg7w+9/pk3GFz5g8n4bDIcG0Iz6Cw9fYVRUZpT8iAilcZQ64T4Y+UBvZ01TdEdVQwSjS1K0+6u3gNztrdAb2pMCnY/zgHHzQ44Ln3GBB95Yd/3nRfze+bubT3F/ZzepGKFN5ANpb3CCWphqVM77LC26h22Voj7o8H16GzcH18MTwetAP9WRCl5LdghsM+9vn/ln09G/Ul/sAN2Q8o9K/4j0JwvriByr9DHhQHYpVOMD8UYRhZEdIgxOFvbMFybjgBH0B0wRdeskUJXZEKHfHl52a2nnoMuVnfC1iniCpVNGN7jNHrXCgakZAzQBV8yu5wgYApd3YZ5lR7Ad+R6BWmBnZQRD16JV2wNYyHEpA5VyRHdYjr0uJWQN3bVqHIl/oSoDFAMVcSgRFTJ196XBHvDqMJXPU0kdglGalHMILsRGsfGyCbFKTNkUhFoldAbRhboIuBY4gb1dV+yMLEdG0w+p5jbzOVtHjgjITGkSiozo04goRk4IRQSJYPJ4HdZukwYWCYzmbGccUoE2siBGaHS4KSxyaHGmpBXl/gO7VZQN7nmsF7lQQqXDAThBXVtS9S3dEkvzQukJ8YQxW1Wq1YGvbNUZgC7cQlAsFmXfGEqjiKgamxp0OB4PV2KxFC7ykd+/eXfuDbj5drJUShXmqpeVJMAnZpjE2IWC2sjLqdyFMpYVVO8Er9AZGskQSvT0FAX7gdaQjsP4mvFiEHNhrU7IE5KF4FnmCVxli65chXWvKIwMVNBaELboEu/mOVrW6Wc4A+VW1+ROcPyaq2EM9BwScF1F+Y9GRcNE7IVxNj44/vFE3w1Bj8MR8PRAKpAv2g365ps3boFGyUHvOe0M51RBcsGz0OtzDvSqXFPCJw14B+IRcrfAwW6mHLve5FaJmqcq+XcOB3Elob1w1ZpzgIMAngorJ+gUzmgbeTTLFMfau4IHABmA6/PYypP0MFMtwW/7PLJHF8QMX9CD2HDZY5BYRwQnUWZmKNqfUin6sEDe8NvoDfDXMqKNH2Xn/jQJwzO+hfnTXert/7LfYe9Rp3p18L0a2aMEvOFAa7e286y455FEq+dF98zwKDOzM13ATTo8NZ4m73hbb+AwJAsOSIebryN9Tf7DCnrXO+QyyVAnMWZhNouHaov4SbcIDtgTYuxkkDYFV+/A6WPaVenHKRbsV7DrY2dIMov85mh8nzPb+kW9/djwOWSUQntKGY4yI8h5H8XRXZRrm/pTSF2IH6FZB9uhYODK7ynyMFTGO0HbGBWaSxoaPKeAlMFzBSpMhG74s6wazemBAbMQDEPbP023QrX3WOCv0Gf7+0LH7V3kZGk+mTPcopP298HNf0/UEsHCHSgcx1ZDQAAUEoAAFBLAwQUAAAIAAB0f4FRog6KjAAYAAAAGAAAGAAAAFRodW1ibmFpbHMvdGh1bWJuYWlsLnBuZ4lQTkcNChoKAAAADUlIRFIAAAC1AAABAAgDAAAAwv3H6QAAAKVQTFRFAwMDCwsLExMTGhoaIyMjKysrMzMzOzs7Q0NDS0tLU1NTW1tbY2Nja2trc3Nze3t7Pz+fbm62dXW6f3+/g4ODjIyMk5OTm5ubo6Ojq6urs7Ozu7u7g4PBjIzFkpLInJzNoKDPpaXSq6vUsbHYurrcw8PDy8vL09PT29vbxMThysrk09Pp3Nzt4+Pj4ODv6+vr5eXy6+v18/Pz8/P5/v7+AAAA////cgB9AAAAFxZJREFUeNrtXYuW2zaSTfql1ovcncWjCthkTpIpAJkZHGQR/P+37S2qH2q7nbQdt90+Q9mSSBAAr8BCVd3Co78b3+LruxX1inpFvaJeUa+oV9Qr6hX1inpFvaJeUa+oV9Qr6hX1N4k6Ss1DRpYUc0y9nl+rvZyddbxz0yO5S5C71MdXjkhJ40kt0ks+K3V6pb6kyCeiFucCGfZlytbHEULJ5KW6yDGxC459Y+JAXDw+2BELcwwUQ3aOxXMLej5i9D4MGzTvsK4V9jRQMmZDQcIgngtyiiA1OrYd9eAmyB0/AXUHavbBRxe868OTsPGUvFgL+N6bqZO32dmB32CDs56QTMfikE7e8LDAZprjyfqBAs75MfmcyPhBdgocHLnUnHUcUJ3ob/JHU1Eryew5hPxpct3f+Xw46qNnrg9icErRj0ZJ7pJreijVz3K8Izyhnd+sP9xG3+XTUFctF1XI5E6we86loMZHxKdvZGntsdzSSj2dTk4y+vC8tab4mjpkuSHkDU1yjzGlpmDaY9dbEPJo+bEJW3z8HI3HKcfZi18LtRcImJ/ZW+uMMyqsgzzjq1DpXiXeO3YQ0oBeS7P3zMjcyXljY7ViKLJ3lj3nyaOWbjJR8Fysz0G7QDZh9pFc7J+zrfuDhD2K5OmzjafCOMb7wvlOVf1prf0xva9WZkW9ol5RvxXUXIsfMdGdYqoP5uL5l4cjSE+T8rnjdipfR3HxNVHv3fxd2vBVrqOXnq/7KOZk4nuBvi6LZi7A2nCl9WO7qMfRaoPFVnXeSrdT0W9FXNNSPt3UK3str4ja7zcbc1kvt5fp9vbGfs8jbeL1rR9js9u0zeYav+b69jDtrmS/ucoX/B1yf7+7LFfbizLKzeZoLze7eHUzyaZfzSgvG/N9aOUqvSLqfHEVrm76VdnyvLtMV3BBbtLlDaRkf7WX67GD/FwcrtrFfnzXa73o39fLejGu3C3KjHbc3Npju9zbehk37RIFgDrjc8OvKSH9cte+P46rurMX7iJfJqAOh/0WqO1FvHRosnLpDv76slybjQA148mMq3Bpvi+Dr+eNvTbX9nbe5Et3kS6zosbnvr6qDmEZlIbvICveNSejUvcG95QZ0mK0U0WTfAmxGO5uePYd7n85uksIjyWf2ObhbQWj8M2iPHerFb5Fzdd3m+Oqr/8TUD9SkzPS2fo7CQ8m5DEROj1DcT9EEdpD9yuSxrPlR2/lXXHPT2INL0VNXIrANrbiRIZEKtwTRw7CJKmkzG4ksPASU/RUg4vQEkmiOBSq3uRISXlbCbbEgIsRfD4m4ZGtZhOQdAFfCqnHiG+fcRHalHmpyFthIMgizkVk5xhfZGVC4Wi8UiSrysM7qAjwLI0RQBXMIFHDHUGkJlcOPhifaWi8QZCBGviY87Mb0mQGUaOZ+xJ4sB61OGddNDiECprIDWOSc6B7IG/DHn1g1Tp+cm5Eh4q8m8l4ehHqBmmotdUOA95wpvEmnLZKmlihrZGKDPquNbosdbneNM9YLrBrYykJTdjH6bIeF/0sp7PFB+h9qUmPK+pCxUhoZfnuANL7UvAlvbG9d/AHr7aQwPuc/YyuQ2b/vOj9V3tP3j+yN1ZX0Xw55+JzSbWUOiDNI1eNiKSec00BYpfaSJqnIVPwAV+FGxo5D6S2VN1wqWhET9CaBYVjbXAGudTOkpFaKKGCwa7k3izuk9CfEu5dIN9LWdyylP5C74kc+x2klyYV5QIRCBMsJfPkOWVHcSYXyXOfjEYdzCyOIJ7E1AidYIl84f9QeR5hdmIaTglFotdEjVMcHQU/k2UkGFc9kSOVZG8YncGeyuKWs88v1HzQDQ6/OkUJOUnh0XEyYk0lpFrRZtpUaKce0PlllNL0VEsMkRIGFEUNKQ5kQ0pMGUk15K5NiedTcEECKk4BD2CklMLI+vQybocKtaa7shXV5fZSK/NEqtonSPvT2j7VAWmrRV9Rr6hX1F8I9TQfh5/zxNM8+kzzNIVbw1OdbruZ3Mwzb+xU63U6RjuX+a2ghlXapXA8TIcu2+P+SNPxsDlYu+tMe7OLh4PfxrGf0nY/Cb2V2FOyaGsdjKLeZ4YV59nyXGcDO+bnUGB95zxmmcSaFla5XlF/E6jFutK7KKdRKgMqIR5so4DuheYbcYL/GnUAvesp3OyurCS3dkdBQBJ6P5EREDFcalpV716rOx3XWpaTvnCgxkVJjdIfuI9+yZS7y0NpTXvO+XqmrSlYHfK2dnbB4gV/GP5x6tPkgjeUKDgrg8BlQQSdreoyK99jVykQEdfZJ7jO6j3DWa4WrjO5hlP44eqJe2MC+2ZtJLY+GsPWBQNOmtD54aKz8SyqCKa4ZH9RnC8kNGscITLFZSw+hkDqGkuK8L3h84JvjxiVgYPGNBDpYXGl+l7hkocIJz9TRC545QFsJcfIqI8DUilEHeFPQbqvqE9iE3jWnAKB6cBhR6UhUZKOTJElRMevJtdSPxDwAKP746jkn4aHU/kI1ItLXu6bvz/v6RNoYJMWhULhJ/df9DgYfb4fXs31Q/5+OGW+T4uf1BvxbD2H4kBGwfaEYqHZg+YZV5LTixFEL+r0CuS13sf50KzvzhQVaxuqTr1wcxzORednFXsD8gkJ95AP9BOIuXV1sDUQa8YblXgLxpkzhJioOCeE6j6Oo0MANRxDJVqfk09licIkhpHUDuQEXbOg10BkWyCX8RvZQRZH1TiO8lcOC1lV4ksp+uCFMvA50GIiNbpEocrkQ7JOQzuEXw9hj8Ep660uCahz+jjN9yANKb6exoWIpfoKVqa8Qzb7GQtexpae5fwg6qfpIem5mNFjnU9qX6ZwlNb/AuqUILsQxghhoFw0cBGSx6d4SDXkBGin6qEeM9SURNWUhB6ZoKoK9PXwRjhD8QadKBVwGeoNIgXtx66QhAGN6lWpDRbnJbhBqCg5aFqkaW3koGt9qB+B2iV0DHf0bII1tbgJxsSqskea8bA8EHjYT53NZHRSU7UM57YbfzQlqJuL4jg6FaG5CTq39Qn1WJ05ZWk4bw9ugqU6JgvP3aHfQq53sDWWuo24hzPJG/4Y1Boz7D0UFb0+sqiBPqWdPvu4Pyp50YDL2fK5lH386J24j9BPs0w09RQV7Hev5pKGA08VLqnMdwenj4+U6zsRe0dy66mi08W6JDyN+NSHj+dszFKuqLjX8SD0j5ef0XT15ahLIliMpEFJUoGUXBssb45ikgYVs/clE2SxJdj9UkxOsLswYaHYVnIQDYGNkuECIH+glouMDEPPKFcgf1LtcAIxYxmM0qHocFpWiy4FdklQWYSZ1/BlCi+MTkJxGvwjGSkYqOViunokiws0ow8mUnkdOpfvOI8Q/GRP/hPtGb6F6l4qgGMHz46YG3vToO5pCgedMbWHEwWHDDrbz6rb6Vijnhyh3xc9YGPXQKZODuSZXhqdRP+pJeWcaon6FQdNqSSL5iuijyDjSYycOhJbQapkeJVIzbHjNOMRJXicEPrapeSG7CNreqoafkxS4edqYBnpVSury7GGKlF9wfkQgEBCzrjDp7OC/idRyfZe7i/NCrx67fDgq3rzNbcEuYbfoYMQOmFhGfzQsQ8Px6ml2tv48q9n5FoF6ohu5VTxQszg3Dj4DrGztxyh/S2kPKuj5OBd2PgmUAskD057YyUBQQQ2Em8okxHQ7xvBtdNQfAXfSB1enJS3gPoDryd9uX8FpGtk4a2g9l5iBaXWWe0u9gRqD70BuYYt1JhAq5D1VkuH0RuVVJPAjy+9SAXLik6DEaGcQgZVZ0aB4nSo6KIjo7XXAi3uVPXgoHbbW9GRUNTr2mgWxWOXtIyswl683KLPEzFcuqoz9AVWLGmoQVkTs21hBq0iVSScrW2NZheRAn4lewt9qbPhY/ez9RZaZoYfBwYHegVnzrKZHQo6uLGaydkDbJ/Hvagbo3RtdDvDTDZHsPlqfF+OeigjYnbis1FqmFjXD4BaGZZ51AlMD7Y4ks5MbnArQausWEvlCORqoo20GRBBHA82dCPFw/fU4UdcMlYda4YbjKysqA3cBR7GwCmn1gnOr2946883HP+aXJ/MXf1Di1L6E7O42OKaHtzf8hnN5jNst6qU4dV1VF6Fr/akhrCUIQ7S2d3petN41lKgVU6lqBMKpyW4ZRIASkEsF0Ma4BUxXNbW3BxU2FHlyITcanCbejOyFFAn1qOE60mdyKG3fY7IPdcbLXk3G9wcwjE7tYxwRYkn6wp4NgU8+QAR9XxkpyZfR6MnFRKnA84DnqFHGvqyAUvROfOEaiC3uAIpIbGgYWzh+4H1EFxXXbah0+rR/9sIhiGg3SuRgxs3gYy9kIHB/4K3LDpyDKuYGI6busMx1qyD0APmMFZkgoguxjTiR2mkDMIbBf8jdS1YYuguxYJjnceiQ9Tw00OhDmpa0XWQVaez4RY5EtxtKKSeMutsU5EeY8+SKMeXeaqfLG3lfYtZvpyV6Y3qec95stTktKDldD1CrGuMEP47eA85wGTuM51ynq+16k0eOqmuv3ksK1qRLgGpvMST+ssjZiq8KofWuNAzGDUZ6pygUkG7IMFzGDoXYlLRj5YmdAAIMPsBsWVowqr0XMUTyjnTnAoEGyzfRAOV32xAtdCdUJoQcPUZQVcYgm4sOpOHWYBbmQUaMEWdsOH6y3y+cIrWRq9RqzY446adElRyJ11TVQgsbeCnRFuDdwamJ/TAYYTMydmKqwQ/0eMrVYZO8GBtDOpmUXHXlWQ49rokrFQvTjg0TkjjCY0CQ5Gih/YIAbZY1Gp8ir7u78TbwEc/9Nw+YqZyqc9wn/uK2yesqEohLOainIIBcmYZ5DwOiJ/T30da5et4Tx16U6IbgRuxeDzRDF0HsakJ5tjpkAD4umhAjEHKPSxIgn5lToPB2K3GXj0E4wujdri1rvEzFfze6goocEQYnkzLCMvApaNXHgZBrQyKxrkdjC/qTRC5aNJ8VCP6pf3rfj8c0IWXIFccT1ZE9bNFVw9XoQbPll/1LywhK5dZUa+oV9R/CfU2jbRv9wF8aG47l4fxAR3h78ss4B5o9GWc3w5N1Y/FnO7qkY9zbRx72B9oh/+uvzbqtDsOv7vdH3dTqLvdNvSb3cFvt8Ptt3t/E3a7vcl1fzwc9u543JrjYUO30347306bMA57v+nzbrufbo/7w6GZQ5inbQjtlVEf502XaTP57VUr+92xju0+ms2+W54Pu1sdCbodcbvfH/112GxMOm6P2/3x9riz23ns0M4jbOxhv5umvTE7M+1sOBvEfCXUujCtgw52XbGms69Hzhpq0cnrteRWi3U6Jt8yfLOUwWZzzbI/9IR/o2VU0JUTp5YXPov/bdSv3xufe9q1rzrkU1Gf2u5+M4J89nX2sO8mhTxlG/UkZjpC01M+r668Ouq2zBkoVmPwMbshkbvOTMiDdPwYBC3pwF7kostocsc76kgRiwQR8SWQrd6mEV1KIFw6+8a+Oup01DYrNFt/DM53mr2OjZs0dKyalt03vCOczDjOjQ1gkhUwZWvEL6jhlLcxW+Q8eKuj1/21Ud/doGicFh9jiaBVnOh6FyTqLDF9a4bKy8ooJJhQdNGHapx6F28oS3Qt46vltTeuqL8y6hKXeFdKUdfDpFIDrGLTpUkcci3BQ1hTClUlXhctMawkcuBSdrUklW8dhu4WJlZHrusXQV13y7Qe54zTkQL2R+KQvCEHVu4LmHmBZQdnH1YmWcbyvSl59jb4+TQeMuwEgt/D5A+Ow5dBfaLfovraOp02GXJJVIPkEqTqcsWqF/OIJYlkvMOso/yxRh3LV80ekDl0XUEopXxxuX4Y2Djbt+c5Z+QDyHTJ39ob/8iin5pJQzntyRqwh3YfDy24HPa7w36+V9Rdnvbek3q0Zf3z65BCqWYSUk851dRcKVSqjJ6bLZB2+NitFA/vI0DPpFpJ5wbpIkWoHqiQwjHUJk51UHPINDIMqvpVAo1TdNZwgi++qJ762XRIdfAigieOw8MfOepoEBTESDq1CGqDTRbrDWu0LxyXKKBG3qfI6qvoQKmPpgXdeIm6DlN2XV7spzz8nh2KzTqP24mfyafPpkMavDcD9SCgJqopQo6qOCK0dxBd3TjpbGwJKS1Tg2SZpY2DAP0C1RI1OYyiF0BtltWQ0EG43JM+nZBk6GyjHGMO/XP2xmW874Nc9c8fa/9zHvTHF1Y/ZEW9ov62UC90609KlaY7YC52aBkBkTwadJt+pK+DmnZjPl+1GKZ3rpsxDoa+iwfl3AeP33m1vT7SxfZS6GK3718Ftd/wdi43126XNgEW8vZCbq+PUM03t9d5cxNuLsug7eHaXNPNjRyur8luR72wu2H2tIn5K7X11XQzH+dyafYXu6s+3IG2HUj9vl7MN/tbg7avl5d8czFtdruDjTfmMPrFvBt+R5cH93VQe5WQec9X+bvp4qDndCOXdfANXZhba+0BMnB53b/fmq3xh4O7lYtgrv0mbiyk6yv1RnGDqR/3MqY0yxh5l82OIb2H+aJOu5R28P51UQG34z57pAzeHYrs966Le2uaL1/f7L9Bfd37+AZRfwu2cWnY+yH8/8Nr/Db6b7//+/ff/n1OZO/dzHLvtJ7vYNo+5In2v/ggP4haV3CSTnSvkvqvP/30y79+/PXv//jHzz/8+M/xz3/9+uvvLQsoVNdtZ0aizC7nEkGrcuk6bSyBaNmiIclcdPHAsm6gRqnKFiRWFKrLQoOu+6nUSOVzoNbpUrqxMhUbZPztbz/846cf//7PX3758Yd///bzf//8w+/JenCo5O3MY1lpRzayzUJU56C0DYTMtOh04hQl53jyJYGE6ZRA551uJQ1qNpXuD2yVsX0O1AkcrCnD7VnGv3766acffvzpxx9//t+///ALDv/nv36taM8ImipFl2S0ArJVijQ0XI9Z14WhTSMYF8hcXJZw5ISLeMUGtmbnwV26xKZROcFDKF+gN/7fi7TOHyqkdcfdd1urvxMTq4/qoH+JpTGfgFqnAZ8Bq3BD4Z7yXVK8m6781lBXeYC4nBqnyzV1ShbptlM9Sn2DqFvRsaHHpk8VWmOcFILuxvfeMtnVoq+o3zTq7qou0OxdB0d9Gz51WMk4ml8WA4iuwcu6TcayMKYvAwK6YEBar+3rtbVqvKSzsCddRwo3w7m27KavA0Wki0R1WcCwholMG8HbybKQJ+Nc+lqoG+mfWIDvRlQI/kSQFHXGeuAYdUeN0PQvbcTBNRSvG3ME/EC4cDFKovpm5foUQThbfJe+4EK8VYe8FdQ6/f/MogdeVsbBe24VCsPnEd6ibQR/Oh8vqTMYitOl4uwsxVTfph8Soq7Qemx63QA363aYeEkH1ct1lesV9TepQ+K5DiknHbKsexzQIZHfog5JT/pbedAhwTqK0mItb1GHSGZ5VMk5pnd0CMsq1yvqT3p9nbVJXSeVcgplFNK5nRWERv+ciS6BPu0GoBM++7J/ugNTL8U1a2LmhH+6ibWu8u+Flg3RS82nXdbVfVlqazqXFCQp6UrqpLsC6BLE6NPLNvT6cEwVusMOaxtNHGary5udmUn/PJiTDAbjj7qFiK4GJRsrOxlu8s77aThfJupiNZgqUXcMZF3RySgzxRDCrBvcT+SOVvc5m53uJOjHEm11neivtLWUPuCEgL2EoFNaokhiEEmRGErRiS1U4UCFFAvpJv4po7UKZfVcQHzKSCGKbkMSdc9A6HVdWK1OYxg6QQbo8ENFwIuChl9l6K47IaL+/JZ647uavbay6pAV9Yp6Rb2iXlGvqFfUK+oV9Yp6Rb2iXlGvqFfUK+oV9Yp6Rb2iXlGvqFfUK+oV9Yp6Rb2iXlGvqFfUK+oV9Yp6Rb2iXlGvqFfUK+oV9Yp6Rb2iXlGvqFfU/yGo/x8tMHBDU0MpDwAAAABJRU5ErkJgglBLAwQUAAgICAB0f4FRAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFQAAAE1FVEEtSU5GL21hbmlmZXN0LnhtbK1Uy27DIBC85yssrpWhj0uF4uRQqV+QfgDFi4MEC+IRJX9fbMWJq8pV3ObGssvM7IzEenu0pjpAiNphQ57oI6kApWs1dg352L3Xr2S7Wa2tQK0gJj4eqvIO46VsSA7InYg6chQWIk+SOw/YOpktYOLf5/nAdKkmAl7IGdo4OI64oeMjkHIZW5HK9JkIjh6C7lvCcKeUlsAnCAPTZlVdV1DaQF3Gw+kqQGVjai/SviFsVtfVBGi1qNPJQ0OE90bLQRA7YEsHD+h0dZqKDMKWaLCQBC1LzHD2gKxvLwKNkFKJNd4d+M2h0l0OgwnxmQkpwUApXWAyh9B7MM/5P64bU4kZewk0ayqnCAtjOd/R0KobiMvUw/KU0snA/TMqW6ffc/gb7m6f7ScKbSJL45F67GZItBUdsL5fWNbsx7ey+QJQSwcISzdNnj8BAACRBAAAUEsBAhQAFAAACAAAdH+BUV7GMgwnAAAAJwAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG1pbWV0eXBlUEsBAhQAFAAICAgAdH+BUfV1COHgAQAA7AMAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATQAAAG1ldGEueG1sUEsBAhQAFAAICAgAdH+BUdASbagzBwAAEzIAAAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYwIAAHNldHRpbmdzLnhtbFBLAQIUABQAAAgAAHR/gVEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANAJAABDb25maWd1cmF0aW9uczIvcG9wdXBtZW51L1BLAQIUABQAAAgAAHR/gVEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAfAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgKAABDb25maWd1cmF0aW9uczIvaW1hZ2VzL0JpdG1hcHMvUEsBAhQAFAAACAAAdH+BUQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARQoAAENvbmZpZ3VyYXRpb25zMi9zdGF0dXNiYXIvUEsBAhQAFAAACAAAdH+BUQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAfQoAAENvbmZpZ3VyYXRpb25zMi9mbG9hdGVyL1BLAQIUABQAAAgAAHR/gVEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALMKAABDb25maWd1cmF0aW9uczIvbWVudWJhci9QSwECFAAUAAAIAAB0f4FRAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADpCgAAQ29uZmlndXJhdGlvbnMyL3Rvb2xiYXIvUEsBAhQAFAAACAAAdH+BUQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHwsAAENvbmZpZ3VyYXRpb25zMi9wcm9ncmVzc2Jhci9QSwECFAAUAAAIAAB0f4FRAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABZCwAAQ29uZmlndXJhdGlvbnMyL2FjY2VsZXJhdG9yL2N1cnJlbnQueG1sUEsBAhQAFAAACAAAdH+BUQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAngsAAENvbmZpZ3VyYXRpb25zMi90b29scGFuZWwvUEsBAhQAFAAICAgAdH+BUbT3aNIFAQAAgwMAAAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA1gsAAG1hbmlmZXN0LnJkZlBLAQIUABQACAgIAHR/gVH2NrMiogoAAKU/AAAKAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABUNAABzdHlsZXMueG1sUEsBAhQAFAAICAgAdH+BUXSgcx1ZDQAAUEoAAAsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA7xcAAGNvbnRlbnQueG1sUEsBAhQAFAAACAAAdH+BUaIOiowAGAAAABgAABgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgSUAAFRodW1ibmFpbHMvdGh1bWJuYWlsLnBuZ1BLAQIUABQACAgIAHR/gVFLN02ePwEAAJEEAAAVAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALc9AABNRVRBLUlORi9tYW5pZmVzdC54bWxQSwUGAAAAABEAEQBwBAAAOT8AAAAA");
  // Всё!
});
</script>
<div id="odf"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, плагин мне помог!